# ordering of functions

Tags: c

I want to know the ordering of functions in a given source file (and ultimately which header files they correspond to), for purposes of knowing the ordering of lib includes.
Is there a "canonical" automated way (i.e. not trial and error) to get this info?
I'm good with sed/awk hacks but is there a "better way"?

Comment: Probably should be migrated to Stack Overflow. @a9usr: You do not need to do anything about this. A quorum of high rep users can do so if they agree.

Comment: I think that you're mistaken to think there's any relation between the order of functions in a source file and the order of includes/libraries...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right.  It is indeed the order of the includes/libraries that matters here; I only need to determine what functions are present, not necessarily the order in which they are called.  Let me rephrase my question: I'm interested in (a) making a list of the functions that are used in a given source file, (b) matching those functions to their respective header files, and (c) determining in what order the header files need to be listed such that there are no missing dependencies (where one header file, or lib, may depend on the presence of another).